# How to make Spring Boot application run despite whether a datasource is available

Tags: java, spring-boot, database-connection

In my Spring Boot application, a datasource is configured. `application.properties` is like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_db
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
```

The application code looks like:

```
public class Foo {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private List<String> getDataFromDB(String user) {
        List<String> data = jdbcTemplate.query(
                    "SELECT ... FROM ...;", /* the detail ommited */);
        return data;
    }
}
```

The code works fine. However, if the database server isn't available, Spring Boot would fail to start:

```
2018-01-17 14:03:30.310 ERROR o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool     [182][main][][][] Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    ...
2018-01-17 14:03:30.314  WARN o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl    [204][main][][][] HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2018-01-17 14:03:30.318  WARN ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[546][main][][][] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
2018-01-17 14:03:30.336 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication              [827][main][][][] Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    ...

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've omitted many lines of error messages.

In my application, the database isn't necessary, it's only used for *improvement*. I would like to run the application even if the database isn't available, but be noticed such failure.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have my Spring Boot application continue to run if it could not connect to the database by setting the following parameter:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```